# Unable to get localhost running in browser even though terminal says listening on localhost

Tags: angular, npm, windows-7, angular-cli

Just created new app with the help of angular cli. Now I started the server where I get the message in terminal that server is listening on localhost:4200.
Refer the below image.[image]

Now when I am visiting the localhost, it says "**localhost took too long to respond.**" and finally it doesn't open neither in mozilla nor in firefox.

```
Environment
Windows 7
Angular 12
Node v12.1.0
npm 6.13.4
```

Also I did it many times but never faced this issue, however this is first time I am doing on my personal system.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

For good measure, you should try:

```
http://127.0.0.1:4200
```

It may be that your system can not resolve `localhost` to its IP address.

If that does not work either, make sure nothing else is running on port `4200`, or try to run it using a different port.

Comment: Tried http://127.0.0.1:4200 and also I run my server in different port but still not working